# how to change base value of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

i am writing a program with very large sparse graphs and i want to save them using scipy.sparse. when there is no edge between two vertex i want to put in the matrix the value inf, so 99% of the values in the matrix will be inf. if i will use regular sparse matrix it's will not help because the base value is 0 and not inf.

so my question: how can i change the base valuse in sparse matrix.

details:
sys.version = 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has no concept or allowance for a 'base' or 'fill'.  `pandas` sparse does.  For your purposes what differences does such a `base` make?  Just display?  Multiplication or other math?

Comment: I need the inf value when i make calculations with the distaces in Dijkstra's algorithm, and it is appearing so much that I thought to use the sparse matrix.